# how to load my page with sidebar hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have created a sidebar that hides with the .click() function targeting an image with the id of "cross".

It is my goal to have page load with no sidebar (.sidebar_menu) visible, and with my menu hamburger (.bars) visible . How do i do this?

HTML:

```
        <img class="bars toggle_menu" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnooxiorz/image/upload/v1502388038/thinbarsfinal_knx5mw.png">
        <div class="sidebar_menu">
            <img id="cross" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dnooxiorz/image/upload/v1502391349/cross_tcn6yk.png">
                <center>
                    <a href="index.html"><h1 class="boxed_item">HELLO</h1></a>
                </center>
                <ul class="navigation_selection">
                    <a href="#"><li class="navigation_item">Projects</li></a>
                    <li class="navigation_item">About</li>
                    <li class="navigation_item">Resume</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#cross").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");
});

$(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
});
```

});

Best,
John

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var hideSideMenu = function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");
  };

  hideSideMenu();  

  $("#cross").click(function(){
     hideSideMenu();
  });

  $(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
      $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
      $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
  });
});
```

Basically, you need to perform the action performed inside your #cross click function, also on the document load to have that as an initial state.

Wrapping it in a `function` will help you keep the functionality to be executed upon close all in one place. I recommend you do similar for showing the side menu by wrapping the actions in a function and calling it like above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the classes in the HTML page, so It loads with the sidebar hidden.

```
<div class="sidebar_menu hide_menu">...</div>
<img class="bars toggle_menu opacity_one" src="...">
```

Or you can use:

```
$("#cross").click();
```

Inside `$(document).ready();` so when it loads, the image that toggles the sidebar gets clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add tge `hide_menu` class in your mark-up:

`<div class="sidebar_menu hide_menu">`